# Unable to remove right action button "LAUNCH" for IOS Push notification

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am currently having problems trying to remove the action button in both IOS local and remote notifications.

For remote notifications, I am using JavaPNS library.

```
   PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex();

    try {
        payload.addCustomAlertActionLocKey(null);
       ...
```

For local notifications, I have set the UILocalNotification's hasAction property to NO.

I have tried entering null values into the addCustomAlertActionLocKey but the action button still appears as 'Launch' in the notification. The JSONObject output, which fulfils the IOS requirements are shown as such:

```
{"aps":{"alert":{"body":"hello there","action-loc-key":null},"sound":"somesound","badge":1}}
```

I am currently running on Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 with JDK 1.6 and GlassFish server 3.1.
The IOS application is built on IOS 5 using xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is similar to mine and might be linked to :
http://openradar.appspot.com/10308591

Which ios are you testing on?